# Delphi Firemonkey Android TEdit UpperCase Duplicating Text

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I'm using Delphi Seattle, and have an `edit` and I want the typed text to be written in `uppercase`. I'm using this code:

```
procedure TF_Quiosque.edtCadNomeVisitanteChangeTracking(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edtCadNomeVisitante.Text := AnsiUpperCase(edtCadNomeVisitante.Text);
end;
```

The first letters come out correctly, but from the third letter the text begins to duplicate in `Edit`.

Comment: First of all - don't use ansi function with unicode string, but in any way your code on Berlin works fine

Comment: @AlexEgorov I can't use Berlin right now.

Comment: This is not work under Android? For me this is works in Windows, can't check under Android now. Change your line to `edtCadNomeVisitante.Text := edtCadNomeVisitante.Text.UpperCase;`

Comment: @AlexEgorov In Windows works perfectly, the problem is under Android. I've tried `edtCadNomeVisitante.Text := edtCadNomeVisitante.Text.UpperCase;`but the compiler returns an error of `There is no overloaded version of 'UpperCase' that can be called with these arguments`

Comment: My error - `edtCadNomeVisitante.Text.ToUpper` should be used

Comment: @AlexEgorov Your code worked after i disabled the Predictive Text. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you must choose the propertie of TEdit *KeyboardType* to *Alphabet*.

[image]